# How to access Application Object in Asp.net MVC Web Api Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I know in Asp.net MVC controller, we can access the application like this:

```
HttpContext.Application["AppVar"]
```

But in the Web api controller, there is no HttpContext, how to access the application Object then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the http context still exists and it's a core component of ASP.Net. how you gain access to it is the issue at hand.

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["AppVar"].
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Web API 2 ("HttpContext does not exist in the namespace "System.Web"...) so in this case, OP's question remains unanswered.  Is there more information for Web API 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
object context;
if (Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out context))
{
    var application= ((HttpContextBase)context).Application; 
}
```

you can get HttpContext object from Request.Propertiies